# jQuery unbind() on toggle, then toggle out bind()

Tags: jquery, toggle, bind, unbind

I'm having trouble re-binding my function after I've unbinded it.

I wanted to unbind the toggle to all siblings(), which seems to work... then on toggle off re-bind the siblings() back to their original state.

Here is my js

```
function filterme(id, name){
$(id).toggle(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $(this).parent().siblings().children().unbind('click');
    $(this).parent().siblings().css({opacity: '0.3'}, 800);

    elements = $('body').find(name);
    $(this).addClass('clicked');

    if(elements.length > 0) {
        if($(name+':visible')) {
            $('div.row:visible').fadeOut('200');
            $(name+':visible').parent().fadeIn('200');
        }
    }
}, function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('div.row').fadeIn('200');
        $(this).removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).parent().siblings().css({opacity: '1'}, 800);
        $(this).parent().siblings().children().bind('click');


});
}


filterme('a.under-pound', 'div.lowest-price');
```

Comment: You can just bind click, or technically you can, but it should have a function to go with it if you expect it to do something. If using jQuery 1.7+ you should have a serious look at the on() / off() functions instead.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into the on/off functions

What do you mean by 'It should have a function to go with it? '

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a click handler like this:

```
function myClickHandler(e){
  // do something with event (e) here
}

...
.bind('click', myClickHandler);

...
.unbind('click', myClickHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

The .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements.

When doing:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().children().bind('click');
```

You are binding the click event, but there is no handler (no function to execute) so nothing much will happen.

Somewhere in your script you probably have a function that executes on the click event, something like:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().children().click(function() {
     alert('someone clicked me');
});
```

otherwise why would you need to unbind the click event to begin with, your trying to get rid of a click event, and then reattach that click event, but just calling .bind('click'); won't do that, it needs to have the entire function set once again.

The way you usually do this is to create a function, like so:

```
function whatToDoIfSomeoneClicks() {
     alert('someone clicked me');
}
```

Now you can bind that function to the event :

```
$(this).parent().siblings().children().bind('click', whatToDoIfSomeoneClicks);
```

Then you can unbind that function:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().children().unbind('click', whatToDoIfSomeoneClicks);
```

and rebind the same function to get it back again:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().children().bind('click', whatToDoIfSomeoneClicks);
```

and as of jQuery 1.7 you should replace bind() with on(), and unbind() with  off().

Comment: *and as of jQuery 1.7 you should replace bind() with on(), and unbind() with off()*

This is not true. You should only switch to on() or off() if you are currently using delegate() and/or live(). The click() and bind() have not been deprecated (yet) :-)

Comment: [jQuery states](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) : "As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements."

Comment: oh bull*cks you're right ... it's good to learn new things every day

Answer (score 0):

@user863739: This is your code

```
$(this).parent().siblings().children().bind('click');
```

So you bind 'click' to .... ahem to .... to what? The jQuery gods obliged you to add (at least) one more parameter to specify to what the 'click' event will be bound. It has to be specified as a function reference (as Billy Moon said). Without this, it would be like trying to bind a tie without having a neck.

Comment: I've tried adding the second parameter although still no luck.

Comment: .unbind('click', filterme);
.bind('click', filterme);

var filterme = function(id, name){ 
// stuff
}

Comment: To quote you "Sorry, I'm a little confused"

filterme is not an event handler. Where should it get its parameters from? Event handlers usually come with a single parameter which is the event object.

Comment: maybe you need to define the `filterme` function before trying to bind it. This is because when you define functions as a variable, they are defined on the fly, as the code is executed, so can not be used before they are defined. Also, to re-iterate, it should be passed one event parameter. Good luck, and godspeed!